# AngularJS get id of element clicked and use in controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I just began learning AngularJS, and I am trying to create a pretty simple web application. Right now, I have some users. Each user is displayed in an individual table and each user has its own details which is displayed in a table under it. 
[image]

```
$scope.userList = [{username: "Bob_t", detailsId: 1}, {username: "Mike_V", detailsId: 2}];
$scope.userDetails = [{Name: "Bob", Age: 20, id: "1"}, {Name: "Michael", Age: 18, id: "2"}];
```

You can see that each user has a reference to it's corresponding details (detailsId in userList corresponds to id in userDetails).

Basically, what I'm trying to do is initially have the details table hidden for each user. And when someone clicks the expand button for a specific user, open that user's corresponding details table and populate it with that user's details. What I'm having trouble with is getting the detailsId from the clicked expand button and then using that to query my DB to get the correct user's details to display in the table under it.

```
<div ng-repeat="user in userList | filter:searchBox">
                    <div class="uk-panel-box-secondary uk-overflow-container tableDiv uk-margin-large-bottom">
                    <table class="uk-table uk-table-hover uk-margin-top">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>Username</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                    </table>
                    <a class="uk-margin-bottom uk-margin-left" id="expandIcon" ng-click="isOpened=!isOpened; showOrHideDetails(isOpened, param)" ng-class="{'uk-icon-plus-square-o': !isOpened, 'uk-icon-minus-square-o': isOpened}"></a>  
                 </div>  
                 <div class="uk-panel-box-secondary uk-overflow-container uk-margin-top uk-margin-large-left uk-margin-bottom tableDiv">
                    <table class="uk-table uk-table-hover uk-margin-top">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>Name</th>
                                <th>Age</th>
                                <th></th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                          <tr ng-repeat="details in userDetails" id={{user.id}}>
                            <td>{{details.Name}}</td>
                            <td>{{details.Age}}</td>
                            <td>
                                <a href="" class="uk-icon-hover uk-icon-pencil-square-o icons"></a>
                                <a href="" class="uk-icon-hover uk-icon-trash icons uk-text-danger" ng-click="delete($index)"></a>
                             </td>
                          </tr>
                    </table>  
                 </div>  
 </div>
```

my controller:

```
$http({
        method : "GET",
        url : "http://database:8081/userAccounts/"
    }).then(function mySucces(response) {
        $scope.userList = response.data;
    }, function myError(response) {
        // $scope.userList = response.statusText;
    });

    $scope.showOrHideDetails = function(isOpened, param) 

        if(isOpened){
        console.log($scope.id)
        $scope[id] = true;
        console.log($scope.id);
            $http({
                method : "GET",
                url : "http://database:8081/details?id=" + index
            }).then(function mySucces(response) {
                $scope.userDetails = response.data;
            }, function myError(response) {
                $scope.userDetails = response.statusText;
            });

        }
        else{
            $scope.showDetails = false;
        }
    }
```

What is really confusing to me is once I get the correct userDetails object after querying the DB, how do I populate the corresponding table with that info?

I know I probably need a model, but this confuses me because the number of users is unknown.

Comment: So you want to display each one per time? It means, when one is open, all should be closed?

Comment: I want to allow multiple to be opened at the same time

Comment: Are you doing a query in DB on every click? Why you didn't get the users with his details once?

Comment: See that's what I initially wanted to do but the API I was given to get details from the DB can only query one at a time....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, your code is a bit confuse..

After each query you're attributing the response (which one is the details of a single user) to the **whole** `array` `userDetails`:

```
$scope.userDetails = response.data;
```

While it should be:

```
$scope.userDetails.push(response.data);
```

In addition, you have a single variable called `isOpened`, for sure it won't work, because you have multiple buttons for only 1 variable.

So my suggestion is to change it to:

```
<a class="uk-margin-bottom uk-margin-left" id="expandIcon" ng-click="showOrHideDetails(user)" ng-class="{'uk-icon-plus-square-o': !user.isOpened, 'uk-icon-minus-square-o': user.isOpened}"></a>
```

Also you have to check if the `userDetail` is already in your `userDetails` array.

Finally, since you want to show the details based on the user, you can use the *native* [**`filter`**](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter), because you already have the `id` *property* of users in both `arrays`, as below:

```
<tr ng-if="user.isOpened" ng-repeat="details in userDetails | filter: { id: user.detailsId }" id={{user.id}}>
```

A *simple* **demo**:

```js
(function() {
  angular
    .module('app', [])
    .controller('MainCtrl', MainCtrl);

  MainCtrl.$inject = ['$scope', '$http'];

  function MainCtrl($scope, $http) {
    $scope.userList = [{
      username: "Bob_t",
      detailsId: 1
    }, {
      username: "Mike_V",
      detailsId: 2
    }];
    $scope.userDetails = [{
      Name: "Bob",
      Age: 20,
      id: "1"
    }, {
      Name: "Michael",
      Age: 18,
      id: "2"
    }];

    $scope.showOrHideDetails = function(user) {
      user.isOpened = !user.isOpened;

      function mySuccess(response) {
        $scope.userDetails.push(response.data);
      }

      function myError(response) {
        console.log(response.statusText);
      }
      
      if (user.isOpened) {
        $http.get('http://database:8081/details?id=' + user.id)
          .then(mySuccess)
          .catch(myError);
      } else {
        $scope.showDetails = false;
      }
    }
  }
})();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app">

<head>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.7/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/uikit/2.26.4/js/uikit.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/uikit/2.26.4/css/uikit.min.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>

<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <div ng-repeat="user in userList | filter:searchBox">
    <div class="uk-panel-box-secondary uk-overflow-container tableDiv uk-margin-large-bottom">
      <table class="uk-table uk-table-hover uk-margin-top">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Username</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td ng-bind="user.username"></td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
      <a class="uk-margin-bottom uk-margin-left" id="expandIcon" ng-click="showOrHideDetails(user)" ng-class="{'uk-icon-plus-square-o': !user.isOpened, 'uk-icon-minus-square-o': user.isOpened}"></a>
    </div>
    <div class="uk-panel-box-secondary uk-overflow-container uk-margin-top uk-margin-large-left uk-margin-bottom tableDiv">
      <table class="uk-table uk-table-hover uk-margin-top">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Age</th>
            <th></th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tr ng-if="user.isOpened" ng-repeat="details in userDetails | filter: { id: user.detailsId }" id={{user.id}}>
          <td ng-bind="details.Name"></td>
          <td ng-bind="details.Age"></td>
          <td>
            <a href="" class="uk-icon-hover uk-icon-pencil-square-o icons"></a>
            <a href="" class="uk-icon-hover uk-icon-trash icons uk-text-danger" ng-click="delete($index)"></a>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

I hope it helps!!

Answer (score 0):

have you tried passing user from

```
<div ng-repeat="user in userList | filter:searchBox">
```

to function showOrHideDetails(user)

Comment: This will work, but once I have the userDetails object, how do I show it in that user's corresponding table...do I need to have a model and populate it in the controller...

Comment: showing pop up will be easy task. I recommand you to exapand the view and how details.

Comment: The details are initially empty, that table should only be populated when the expand is clicked. So I need to query the DB when expand is clicked, find the correct details, and then populate the correct table.

Comment: yes. but what is problem then? May be I think you are pretty clear. :)

Comment: problem is how can I populate the corresponding table with the userDetails returned from the DB